# provider won't show the value on it's own

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I made a provider to get sum up values of multiples instances of class Food and display the sum on a button but for some reason it doesn't show unless I leave and return to the page or hot reload. Please help I'm losing my mind.

I have a list userOrders that contains all items added to the cart and the fold function is supposed to sum up the product of the price and quantity and display it on the button.

**Food**

```
class Food {
  String imgUrl;
  String desc;
  String name;
  String waitTime;
  num score;
  int price;
  int pq;
  int quantity;
  bool favourited;
  List<Map<String, String>> ingredients;
  String about;
  bool highlight;
  Food(this.imgUrl, this.desc, this.name, this.pq, this.waitTime, this.score,
      this.price, this.quantity, this.ingredients, this.about, this.favourited,
      {this.highlight = false});

  int pqProduct(Food food) {
    pq = food.quantity * food.price;
    return pq;
  }
```

**Provider**

```
class FavFood with ChangeNotifier {
  int peeQee() {
    int pqe =
        userOrders.fold(0, (a, element) => a + element.pqProduct(element));
    return pqe;
  }

  void update() {
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**Button**

```
class NextButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<NextButton> createState() => _NextButtonState();
}

class _NextButtonState extends State<NextButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return userOrders.isNotEmpty
        ? Container(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 10.0, 5.0, 5.0),
            height: 60,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              style: ButtonStyle(
                shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                    side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              child: Text(
                '${context.read<FavFood>().peeQee}',
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          )
        : const Text('');
  }
}
```

The button is supposed to update the price when an item is added but it doesn't until I reload

Instance of `Food`

```
Food(
        'assets/images/sha-modified.png',
        'Most Recommended',
        'Shawarma',
        0,
        '15 min',
        4.5,
        1500,
        0,
        [
          {
            'Flatbread': 'assets/images/flatbread-modified.png',
          },
          {'Cabbage': 'assets/images/cabbb-modified.png'},
          {'Chicken': 'assets/images/chicken-modified.png'},
          {'Sauce': 'assets/images/sauce-modified.png'},
        ],
        'A sandwich of sliced lamb or chicken, vegetables, and often tahini wrapped in pita bread',
        highlight: true,
        false,
      ),
```

Comment: what is `userOrders` on the widget

Comment: userOrders is a list of `Food` items

Comment: it would be easier if you could include sample data so that everyone can test and reproduce the same error

Comment: I just updated the post with a sample of `Food`

Comment: I am getting result ,provided item directly on provider, you may use provider to hold that list

Comment: Will using provider to hold the list allow the Button price to be updated when the list is changed

Comment: sorry not sure, it would be easier if you could provide minimal full snippet or git

Comment: https://github.com/shimomaru/2.0

Comment: can you tell me the step to reproduce the error

Comment: Add shawarma or smoothie to the cart and go to the check out page. On the check out page, add increase the amount of any of the items. You'll see that the price won't change unless you hot reload or leave and return to the page

Comment: @AkuKaku's solution worked. But I don't understand how. How does `context.watch<FavFood>();` in the build method change anything. I'm pretty new to flutter so I'm really curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place a `context.watch<FavFood>()` within your build method to actually listen to the changes by `notifyListeners()`.

Also your `onPressed` callback is actually empty, you need to call your `update()` method to trigger the build.

Comment: When I use `'${getCurrency()}${context.watch<FavFood>().peeQee()}',` I get https://ibb.co/jHs2fWD but when I use `'${getCurrency()}${context.read<FavFood>().peeQee()}',` I get https://ibb.co/31Hjdhx like I'm supposed to. Just that it still doesn't update

Comment: Try adding a `context.watch<FavFood>();` in your build method, besides `${getCurrency()}${context.read<FavFood>().peeQee()}`.

Comment: This worked! But how? I don't get it. I thought I tried everything. Why does putting `context.watch<FavFood>();` in the build method fix the problem?

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Placing `context.watch<FavFood>()` in the build method basically "flags" that method for rebuilding whenever `notifyListeners()` is called. This is not the case for `context.read`, hence the importance of using `context.watch`.